# oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of "web"

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to send Gmail from a Python script to myself, and have the following code that used to be working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import base64
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
import os
import httplib2

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from apiclient import errors

from config import MY_EMAIL, CLIENT_SECRET_FILE

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

def send_message(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'sendEmail.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials


def send_email(sender=MY_EMAIL, receiver=MY_EMAIL, subject=None, body=None):
    print("sending email to: %s, from: %s" % (receiver, sender))
    if not body:
        raise Exception("You need a body to send an email")
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    send_message(service, "me", create_message(sender, receiver, subject, body))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_email(subject="Test gmail automatic emails", body="Hello world")
```

My client_secret.json looks like

```
{"web":{"client_id":"23423423423-234234234.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"prime-imagery-4444","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"asdfasdfasdf-trWCLxFdb", "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost:8000/fakeurl"]}}
```

I added in `redirect_uris` as that was the only good advice I found online, but I don't want to redirect. Last time I ran this script, having the `client_secret` was enough to send Gmails from my Gmail account using Python.

Answer (score 9):

Just go to your Credentials in your Google Dev Console and add what it's asking. `http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback` or `https://www.samplesite.com/oauth2callback`. Adding the '`oauth2callback`' is the redirect URI. Check the [Create authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingcred).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue.

So after you add the `redirect_uri` also don't forget to redownload the `clien_secret.json` file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform 3 steps. 
 (step 2 wasn't specified in other answers):

1 )  You add a uri to `Authorized redirect URIs`.
2 ) The `Authorized redirect URIs` uri is equal to the one you entered in `Authorized JavaScript origins` just with a closing slash `/`.

[image]

3 ) Download `client_secret.json` **again** and add it to your working direcory.

[image]

Comment: Can we authenticate using terminal not with the web browser?